# setting Transparency to the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view that contains a scroll view and again that contains a view and then a table view.(this table view has custom cells).

I have a background image for the top most view but the inner most table view background is blocking the image. Tableview  shows a white background .

I have to make the background of tableview as transparent so that the image on the view should be visible.

how to do that. Pls help.

Comment: You should set tableview backGround color clearColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the backgroundview nil before making background as transparent

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: That depends what style the table is. If it's grouped, you need to set the background view to nil.

Answer (score 1):

tablecell.contentview.backgroundcolor = [UIColor clearColor];

Hope it should help..